# How to change the font-size of the part of textarea text in HTML,CSS?

Tags: html, css

My textarea text must  have 2 lines and  2 font sizes. I tried  to change the font size  using span  tag but this doesn't work.

How to achieve that? Please help.

Here is https://jsfiddle.net/arminemash/ccsa4xf8/1/

```
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment">Blah blah blah:&#13;&#10 <span>(blah blah blah)</span></textarea>
```

Comment: Show us your attempts. 'Doesn't work' is awfully vague. Add more detail to the question to specify what isn't working.

Comment: Andrew L span tag is shown as a text like this:   blah blah:
 <span>(blah blah)</span>

Comment: Are you styling it?

Comment: Andrew L.  https://jsfiddle.net/arminemash/ccsa4xf8/2/

Comment: You can't use spans in textareas. Use something like a contenteditable div

Comment: Andrew L In my case how can I use it?I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `<span>`s inside `<textarea>`s. You also didn't style the span. If you want to use `<span>`s inside of some editable, use a `<div>` that's contenteditable. Example:

```
<div id="comment" contenteditable="true">
    Some text <span style="font-size: 30px">LARGE TEXT</span>
</div>
```

The editable region will lose the border, but you can easily add that. The height and width for the text limits will also need to be set. Here is a fiddle:

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccsa4xf8/3/)

Here's another fiddle with more styling:

[Another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccsa4xf8/4/)